# Tried to replace a backslash with another symbol using double backslash and failed

Tags: python, syntax

The code looks like this:

```
a = 'CC(C)CC(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1\tCC(C)C[Mg+].CON(C)C(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1'
d = a.replace('\\', '>>')
d
```

And it returns the same string. The code with a single backslash returns an error.

Tried ' or " quotation marks, the same result.

Comment: `\t` is a tab character not backslash, t. You could use `d = a.replace('\t', '>>')` if that is what you want.

Comment: That `\t` - do you want it to be the single tab character or the 2 character backslash, t characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user19077881 said in the comments, `\t` is a tab character. You may want to use raw strings to treat `\` as a literal character by adding r before your string literal:

```
a = r'CC(C)CC(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1\tCC(C)C[Mg+].CON(C)C(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1'
d = a.replace('\\', '>>')
```

Printing d will give your desired result: `'CC(C)CC(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1>>tCC(C)C[Mg+].CON(C)C(=O)c1ccc(O)nc1'`

Comment: Also worth noting that if `a` is an existing normal (not raw) string then `a = '%r'%a` can be used to convert before the replace statement.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice the t that shouldn't be in the chemical formula